# How to get a Element ID inside a Javascript Custom Element?

Tags: javascript, html, reusability, code-reuse, custom-element

I used this tutorial to reuse my navigation bar in all my pages: [Reusable HTML Components – FreeCodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reusable-html-components-how-to-reuse-a-header-and-footer-on-a-website/)
In short he puts the HTML in a .JS file and calls it on the pages with `<nameOfComponent> </nameOfComponent>`

But to resize to mobile device size, I need to call this script:

```
function topNav_resize() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
console.log("este é o conteudo da variavel x: " +x)
if (x.className === "topnav") {
 x.className += " responsive";
} else {
 x.className = "topnav";
}
}
```

But getElementById comes null

*Does anyone know why? Or a better way to do it?*

**These are the tutorials that I followed:**

[How to do a reponsive Topnav w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp)

[Reuse Header & Footer FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reusable-html-components-how-to-reuse-a-header-and-footer-on-a-website/)

Comment: better use classlist, not className. When did you call function does myTopnav exist on that time?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The Custom Element creates a **shadowRoot** (aka shadowDOM)

That means `document.getElementById("ID")` can't access any elements inside shadowDOM (think of it like an IFrame)

You **could** do `document.querySelector("my-element").shadowRoot.getElementById("id")` (which IFrames can't do)

**But...** that needs `mode:"open"` and this element sets `mode:"closed"`

which means the "outside" world is not allowed to query shadowDOM **at all**

`closed` roots are rarely used... because its a total lockdown.

If you have access to the source, rewrite it to:

```js
connectedCallback(){
  this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).append(headerTemplate.content);
}
```

Why it isn't done in the `constructor`, I don't know

```js
constructor(){
  super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}).append(headerTemplate.content);
}
```

should be fine, see: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-component-102-the-5-lessons-after-learning-web-components-101-h9p